# GCP Service Accounts roles & permissions cross project

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, service-accounts

I have developed the following code for automating the start/stop tasks of some of my instances which do not need to run all the time but to an specific range.

So here is my code: https://github.com/maartinpii/gcp-shst

I created a service account following the google cloud platforms guides (ref: https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-service-accounts https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/service-accounts#service_account_permissions), so I created a service SC-Auto in Project A and then created them in the IAM tab of the others projects and brought it the "Project Owner" role.

Note: From where I am running it I also executed the gcloud auth service-account ... as mentioned [Cross project management using service account](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35479025/cross-project-management-using-service-account)

However, when I execute my code I have the following scenario:

- When executing it calling the project from where I have created the service accounts it works great.
- When executing it calling any other project from where I have set the project owner role, it always retrieve this error

  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "gcp-shst.py", line 45, in 
      response = request.execute()
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/googleapiclient/_helpers.py", line 130, in positional_wrapper
      return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/googleapiclient/http.py", line 842, in execute
      raise HttpError(resp, content, uri=self.uri)
  googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects//zones/southamerica-east1-a/instances//start?alt=json returned "Required 'compute.instances.start' permission for 'projects//zones/southamerica-east1-a/instances/'">

So now I am wondering if it is possible to use the same service account to execute functions in all of the projects where I provisioned it and brang it the correct permissions or if I need to create a different service account per project or if I am doing something wrong...

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After debug and analysis I have found out that the projects that I wasn't able to manipulate with the service account had a **Name** which was different from it's **ID** (Ref: [https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/creating-managing-projects#Identifying projects](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/creating-managing-projects#Identifying%20projects))

So when I replaced the name of the project with the ID it worked OK.