# Google Could Platform App Engine in Project A pubish to PubSub Topic in Project B

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-iam

I am new to GCP, I have done some research to understand how a service in Project A can access a resource in Project B.
I have an GAE in Project A that needs to publish on Pub/Sub Topic in Project B. I have found this [Cross project management using service account](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35479025/cross-project-management-using-service-account) but I am not sure if it does the same thing. Please advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The section "Sample use case: cross-project communication" describes the exact scenario https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/access-control

But most importantly the IAM role defined should be restrictive/appropriate to Project B's resource access

Comment: thanks. One more thing: since service account are unique, when I add a service account (defined in a project) to another project I am actually referring to that same service account, right?

Comment: Should be. That's Because it has the project id associated with it.