# Cross-project ListBuckets when authenticating using service account HMAC keys

Tags: google-cloud-storage, aws-java-sdk

I am trying to access Google Cloud Storage using the AWS Java SDK. My particular scenario is that I would like to use a service account in a project "A" to list buckets in a project "B". [The guide from Google](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/migrating#migration-simple) doesn't cover this type of cross-project access with a service account.

I tried setting `x-goog-project-id` header explicitly:

```java
        // The access id and secret key below are for a service account in project "A".
        BasicAWSCredentials googleCreds = new BasicAWSCredentials(
                "my access id",
                "my secret key");

        AmazonS3 interopClient = AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard()
                .withEndpointConfiguration(
                        new AwsClientBuilder.EndpointConfiguration(
                                "https://storage.googleapis.com", "auto"))
                .withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(googleCreds))
                .build();

        ListBucketsRequest listBucketsReq = new ListBucketsRequest();
        // The project id below is for project "B"
        listBucketsReq.putCustomRequestHeader("x-goog-project-id", "my project id");
        List<Bucket> buckets = interopClient.listBuckets(listBucketsReq);

        System.out.println("Buckets:");
        for (Bucket bucket : buckets) {
            System.out.println(bucket.getName());
        }
```

But I get the following error about duplicate header values:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: Multiple HTTP header values where one was expected. (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 400; Error Code: ExcessHeaderValues; Request ID: null; S3 Extended Request ID: null), S3 Extended Request ID: null
```

Is there any way to get this scenario working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This recently changed. [You can now pass in a header `x-amz-project-id` to specify a project for these operations](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/migrating#project-header), so your service account can "live" in one project but request bucket operations in any other.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the info in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35558464/6003934), you have to add the service account created in project A to the the IAM page in project B. Then add the corresponding roles.

Comment: I have already set up the appropriate permissions. I would have got a permission error if not.

Comment: Where do you specify the bucket you want to access?