# Google App Engine access firebase in different project

Tags: firebase, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I have setup app engine and firebase at **PROJECT A**, the app engine used default credentials, and able to access firebase at **PROJECT A**, however the app engine also need to call

```
verifyIdToken()
```

to verify user in **PROJECT B**.

What would be the best approach to it?

1. I can download the firebase credentials from **PROJECT B**, and use firebase admin sdk to do so, but it seems overkill, because i only needs to verify use token.
2. Setup firebase IAM permission in **PROJECT B** for app engine from **PROJECT A**, so it can access to firebase, theoretically, but in this case, how the app engine get the credentials from firebase in **PROJECT B**? Definitely not default credentials, right?

Answer (score 0):

You can add the necessary roles from Project B to the service account used by Cloud Functions (it will be `<project-a>@appspot.gserviceaccount.com`). You would do this by visiting the Google Cloud IAM console in Project B and assigning the roles appropriately.

Once you do that, you should be able to use default credentials to authorize requests for Project B.

*Note:* There's some nuance here and I haven't directly tried this, but it should work in theory.

Comment: Thanks! However, in this case, I want have both firebase access to Project A and B, how the default credential in app engine distinguish?

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution

[using_a_service_account_id](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/create-custom-tokens#using_a_service_account_id)

and

[Answer from another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35479025/cross-project-management-using-service-account?noredirect=1&lq=1)

After setup the IAM role and policy in project B with project A accouint, simply just do

```
projectB_firebase = firebase_admin.initialize_app(options={
    "serviceAccountId": "firebase-adminsdk-xxxxxxx@[projectb].iam.gserviceaccount.com"
}, name="projectB")
```